# Hover in css - text destroys hovering?

Tags: html, css, class, web

I am actually new in css. so I have 3 boxes on my page, which should change their background opacity when hovering. In general, it works, but I have the issue when I'm not hovering the box directly (the padding area where you can actually hover the  "empty" box area) I gonna hit the text with my mouse, nothing happens. this is really annoying. Is there a method to let the pointer not "track" the text so the box hover works all over the box (without the text interrupt it completely)?

here is my CSS code for the boxes. Thanks!

```
.intro-container-text {
  width: 1000px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20;
}

.intro-text-box1,
.intro-text-box2,
.intro-text-box3  {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300;
  height: 260;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 9px;
  padding: 50px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  /*Schatten*/
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 0px rgba(201,201,201,1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 0px rgba(201,201,201,1);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 0px rgba(201,201,201,1);
}

.intro-text-box1-sec {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300;
  height: 260;
  background: url(../res/img/wall.jpg)bottom center no-repeat;
  opacity: .3;
}

.intro-text-box2-sec {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300;
  height: 260;
  background: url(../res/img/wall.jpg)bottom center no-repeat;
  opacity: .3;
}

.intro-text-box3-sec {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300;
  height: 260;
  background: url(../res/img/wall.jpg)bottom center no-repeat;
  opacity: .3;
}

.intro-text-box1-sec:hover {
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  opacity: .4;
}

.intro-text-box2-sec:hover {
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  opacity: .4;
}

.intro-text-box3-sec:hover {
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  opacity: .4;
}
```

Comment: Hey and welcome to stackoverflow. Could you give us a working example please. You can use something like https://jsfiddle.net/ and add the link to your problem. Lets us get a better idea of the problem

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing the markup, this is more of an educated guess as to being your solution. You need to set the `:hover` on the parent and then define the child as the element you wish to target, such as the below. Also, since your transitions and opacity don't change, you could also use `.intro-text-box1:hover > div` as the selector, so you don't have to repeat your CSS unnecessarily.

```
.intro-text-box1:hover .intro-text-box1-sec {
     transition: opacity 0.3s;
     opacity: .4;
}
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer, i appreciate the "education" tips! I'll try to get this into my mind when doing css scripts :)